Why does my Windows shortcut have a target location of "7" in the properties?
I created a shortcut on my desktop which executes a Powershell command to restart explorer.exe. For some reason, in the properties window, the target location is listed as 7. What does this mean?


You have PowerShell 7 installed and this shortcut is, first, a shortcut to your PowerShell 7 executable.
On my computer, most shortcuts to programs have a Target Location of "application", a shortcut to Windows PowerShell has a Target Location of v1.0, and a shortcut to PowerShell 7 has a Target Location of 7, because this is the folder the target executable is immediately inside: "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe"

Oh geez, you're right. It really was that simple. Thanks.

I didn't know this until I began looking based on your question. TIL
